# Terrible SQL reads performance (culprit update stats?)

Tags: sql-server, performance, t-sql

I'm running on SQL Server 2008 R2 and am trying to fine-tune performance. I did everything I could from:

- Code review of SQL code
- Create or remove indexes as I think appropriate
- Auto create stats ON
- Auto update stats ON
- Auto update stats async ON

I have a 24/7 system that constantly stores data. Sometimes we do reads and that's where the issue is. Sometimes the reads take a couple of seconds or less (which would be expected and acceptable to us). Other times, the reads take several seconds that could amount to a minute before the stored procedure completes and we render data on the UI.

If we do the read again, it would be faster. The SQL profiler would trace the particular stored procedure or query that took several seconds. We would zoom into that stored procedure, and do everything we can do to optimize it if we can.

I also traced the auto stats event and the recompile event. It's hard to tell if a stat is being updated causing the read to take a long time, or if a recompile caused it. Sometimes, I see that the profiler traced a recompile of the read query that took several unacceptable minutes, other times it doesn't trace a recompile.

I tried to prevent the query optimizer from blocking the read until it recompiles or updates stats by using option use plan XML, etc. But I ran into compile errors complaining that the query plan XML isn't valid; that could be true because the query is quiet involved: select + joins that involve a local table var. I sort of hacked the XML and maybe that's why it deemed it invalid. So I gave up on using plan hint.

We tried periodic (every 15 minutes) manual running update stats in order to keep stats up-to-date as much as we can, but that hurt performance. `updatestats` blocks writes, and I'm sure even reads; `updatestats` seemed to maintain a bunch of statistics and on average it was taking around 80-90 seconds. A read that waits that long is unacceptable.

So the idea is to let the reads happen and prevent a situation when a recompile/update stat blocks it, correct? Does it make sense to disable auto statistics altogether? Or perhaps disable auto create statistics after deleting all the auto created stats?

This goes against Microsoft recommendations perhaps, since they enable auto create statistics and auto update statistics by default, and performance may suffer, but any ideas/hints you can give would be appreciated.

Comment: You mentioned "manually updating stats", via `sp_updatestats`? or using another method?

Comment: have you checked your buffer chache hit ratio  or checked to see if you're memory is too strained?

Comment: How is the schema structured? Do most tables use surrogate keys? If so, what is their type? I.e., do most tables use Identity columns? guids? natural keys? How big are some of these tables?

Comment: I don't understand what you are saying the issue is? Are you saying that it is the recompiles that are taking the time? What do you mean by "Terrible SQL reads performance" then? The number of reads is high? Or they take a long time as they are blocked or need to be read in from disc?

Comment: I'll try to answer all of you.
@BradC: using sp_updatestats on only one of the databases.

Comment: @DForck42: yes, I'm using perfmon to track several others counters. BCHR looks healthy at 99-100%. Memory, not strained. I've updated the original post with physical data (8G memory, 300G disk, the DB size ~ 80G)

Comment: @Thomas: yes most tables use surrogate Guid keys. A few tables (that are actually used frequently) have identity column keys supposedly to help at the index level (not sure if it helps or if a guid is more appropriate). Couple of these top tables are 2-3 million rows, ~ 2-3G, the rest are in the 100,000s rows, and 100MB all the way down to a few 10,000s rows, to a few 1000 rows.

Comment: @Martin: I don't think the recompiles are taking the time. I'm still trying to figure out what the issues are (they could be many) :) may be the reads are needing to read from disk the first time, which explains why they're faster next; but it's never consistent; we make sure to read query tables with (nolock) to avoid getting blocked by the writes - is there a chance that this hint works sometimes and not others?

Thanks!

Comment: @sOltan - Guids as keys require special attention. You cannot generate your guids using `newid` or the read performance will be horrid. You must use the equivalent of a NewSeqentialGuid or a COMB guid which replaces part of the guid with a datetime. It is possible this is the source of your performance issues.

Comment: i'm curious as to what the code looks like for one of your sp's that's causing the issue

Answer (score 8):

From what you are explaining, it looks like the below (all or some) might be happening.

1. You are doing physical reads. The quick way you avoid this is by increasing the amount of RAM you throw at the box. You haven't mentioned the hardware specs of your server. Please add details.
2. If you trace the SQL calls then you can easily figure out why the RECOMPILE happened. Look at the EventSubClass to figure out the reason and work towards resolving that. 
   ref: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187105.aspx
3. You mentioned table variables. These are notorious for causing performance issues when NOT using at the right place. If you use table variables in a JOIN, parallel plan is out of the question and no stats also. I am NOT sure how and where you are using but try replacing them with temp tables. And starting from SQL Server 2005, you will get only STMT recompilation at best and NOT the complete SP recompile as it happened in 2000.
4. You mentioned Update Stats ASYNC option and this won't block the query.
5. What are the TOP WAIT STATS on this server? Have you identified the expensive procedures based on CPU, Logical reads & execution count?
6. Have you looked the Page Life Expectancy, amount of IO using virtual file stats DMV?
7. Updating Stats every 15 minutes is NOT a good plan. How often is data inserted into the system? What is the sample rate you are using? What is your index maintenance strategy?
8. Have you looked at the missing indexes DMV?

There are a bunch of good queries to identify problems in more granular fashion using the below queries.

ref: http://dl.dropbox.com/u/13748067/SQL%20Server%202008%20Diagnostic%20Information%20Queries%20%28April%202011%29.sql

There are so many other things to look at but the above is a good starting point.

Comment: That link to Glenn Berry's diagnostic information queries is fantastic. There are plenty of useful queries in it to help diagnose performance issues.

Comment: Hi, please see some of my answers above right under the post.
* I looked at the reason for recompile, and all of them say 2 - Statistics changed.
* auto update stats async: is that good practice?
* page life expectancy is above 500 most of the time, sometimes 2000.
* no strategy to maintain the indexes. 
* will check other things

Answer (score 1):

OK, here is my IMHO catch on this:

- `DBCC INDEXDEFRAG` is worth trying and is an `ONLINE` function hence can be used on a live system
- You could be reaching the maximum capacity of your architectural design. You can **scale up** which can always help but more likely you have to **change the architecture** to achieve better scalability sacrificing simplicity
- A common trick is `partitioning`. You are writing to a table whose index distribution looks nothing like it was a few hours ago - hence degrading performance. This is a massive write, such a table could be divided to daily write and the rest of the data with nightly batches of moving stuff across.
- More and more, people are being converting to [**CQRS**](http://blog.fossmo.net/post/Command-and-Query-Responsibility-Segregation-%28CQRS%29.aspx). You might be the next. This solves the problem by separating reads from writes (a very simplistic explanation).

Comment: `DBCC INDEXDEFRAG` is a deprecated function replaced by `ALTER INDEX REBUILD` and `ALTER INDEX REORGANIZE`.

Comment: Thanks! My SQL Server knowledge is a bit old